# discord.js extracting emails

Tags: node.js, discord.js

The code below lets me get every information about a user in discord. However, I couldn't find a way to get the emails of users. Is it deprecated? Can someone help me with the code?

```
client.on('ready', () => {

  console.log(`logged in as ${client.user.username}`);

  var Count;
  for(Count in client.users.array()){
     var User = client.users.array()[Count];
     /* client.sendMessage(User, msg); */

     //userName += User.username + "#" + User.discriminator + '\n';
  }

})
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [latest stable docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientUser?scrollTo=email), you can use user.email to retrieve the Email from a user account. Seeing as you're not using email anywhere in you're code, I'm not sure what you're asking about when it comes to "can someone help me with the code". I will provide an example, however, on how to retrieve the value.

```
const email = client.user.email; // Will return null if no email is available.
```

From my tests, it seems that the Email variable only shows up for **user accounts**, meaning if you're trying to retrieve the Email of a bot account, it will return null. If you're trying to retrieve the Email of other users, though, that is not a capability provided by the Discord API.