# discord.js extracting emails from discord tag

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am wanting to extract someone's email from their discord tag. Im quite new to coding in this language and I am not sure how to go about doing this. I've been looking around and I found this line of code.

`const email = client.user.email;`

I have tried a bunch of codes and I am unable to understand what I am doing. So could someone help me please write me a code to extract an email from a discord account any way possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888797/discord-js-extracting-emails/48415433), the answerer actually says that it's not possible to retrieve the email of other users. This is also shown on the [discord.js documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) where none of the properties shown list the user's email.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Discord **[OAuth2](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2)** with `email` scope included in order to get the email of a discord user once the user authorizes access to your application.

There are a lot of scopes and some of them are being:

[image]

with that being said, there is no other way of getting email address of other users on discord.