# How do I create commands that only people who buy a patreon tier can use?

Tags: javascript, command, patreon

I need help with how to set up patreon commands to where when somebody buys the tier that is listed they get access to a select amount of commands that only they can use. So basically lets say somebody buys a patreon tier they get access to a command and people who do not buy the tier can not use it, my code is in java script also!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many steps to doing that. I don't know any specifics about the Patreon API or your code, but these are the things you'll have to do.

1. Get the Discord user's email. [discord.js extracting emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47888797/discord-js-extracting-emails/48415433)
2. Check if the user has the Patreon tier using the Patreon API.
3. Depending on if they have the tier, change the action.

This is what I would imagine step 3's code to look like:

```js
// Message handler
if (await hasTier(msg.user)) {
  // Do the command
} else {
  msg.reply("You can't use this command because you don't have the Patreon tier.")
}
```

If you want more specific details, please ask individual, specific questions.